# Objective C - How do I inherit from another class?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

```
- (id) init
{
     [super init];
     //initialitation of the class
     return self;
}
```

I know that when I am inheriting from another class I am suppose to call `super.init`

Does this apply to "inheriting from NSObject" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, usually you have something like:

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // instantiation code
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, because Apple's documentation says `init...` methods should always include a call to `super`. However at present, the `NSObject` implementation of `-init` does nothing, so omitting the call wouldn't prevent your code from working.

The downside of omitting the call to `super` is that your code wouldn't be as robust to future changes; for example if you later changed the inheritance, or if (God forbid) Apple changed `NSObject`'s `-init` method so that it actually did something essential.